# The program Anki won't start

Tags: software-installation, anki

Here is the output I get when I try to launch Anki:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/anki", line 6, in <module>
import aqt
File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from anki import version as _version
File "/usr/share/anki/anki/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
from anki.storage import Collection
File "/usr/share/anki/anki/storage.py", line 11, in <module>
from anki.collection import _Collection
File "/usr/share/anki/anki/collection.py", line 25, in <module>
from anki.sound import stripSounds
File "/usr/share/anki/anki/sound.py", line 87, in <module>
from anki.mpv import MPV, MPVBase
File "/usr/share/anki/anki/mpv.py", line 39, in <module>
from distutils.spawn import find_executable
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.spawn'
```

Answer (score 11):

After installing python3-distutils, it should launch. I had the same issue.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it works for me as well to install the python3 disutils as well, it is probably better to remove the old version you are probably using and downloadind the latest version from 
https://apps.ankiweb.net/#linux
There are specific instructions in that page, how to proceed to install anki.